# How to change where texlive decompress its files during installation? No space on /tmp

Tags: installing

I am trying to install TeX Live 2018 on new Linux Manjaro. I have about 1 TB disk, almost all free space. But Manjaro when it installed made `/tmp` partition very small. (2 GB only for some reason)

```
>df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
dev              2009848        0   2009848   0% /dev
run              2016656     1308   2015348   1% /run
/dev/sda1      951644596 37045788 866188144   5% /
tmpfs            2016656     4648   2012008   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            2016656        0   2016656   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            2016656    38048   1978608   2% /tmp
```

TeX Live installation, (using `install-tl`) uses `/tmp` for decompressing large `*.zip` files and such while it is installing. So I got an error and it stopped saying there is no more space.

Is there a way change this to a different `/tmp` folder? I am looking now at the initial menu that `install-tl` shows up, and I see no option there to change this. It just say `<I> start installation to hard disk`

Here is the error I got

```
....
Installing [2640/3628, time/total: 01:06:33/01:31:27]: pst-fr3d [177k]
Installing [2641/3628, time/total: 01:06:34/01:31:28]: pst-fractal [9020k]
./tlpkg/installer/xz/xz.x86_64-linux: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
TLPDB::_install_package: Decompressing /tmp/A5EAYviamn/9yPFNOU8N1/pst-fractal.doc.tar.xz failed
Installation failed.
Rerunning the installer will try to restart the installation.
Or you can restart by running the installer with:
  install-tl --profile installation.profile [EXTRA-ARGS]
```

I do not know what `EXTRA-ARGS` above is supposed to be and if that is how to make it change where `/tmp` is.

May be I need to set some environment variable?

How to make TeX Live use different `/tmp` folder?

Comment: Why are you not using the official packages from the package repository? I seems like TeX Live 2018 is [already available there](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=texlive). And by the way: The `/tmp` directory normally is half of the size of your RAM (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/tmpfs#Examples)).

Comment: I think it is just using the value of the TMPDIR environment variable, so just set that to something else before starting the installer. Doens't it clean up when it is installing? That is strange.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh because the official Manjaro texlive package that was there on disk, had problems. When I first used it (before trying to install TL), it gave me missing packages on a first trial trying to compile some files I have. I never got missing package problems when using TL. I prefer to use TL always. It is complete.

Comment: @daleif I am trying `/etc/environments` now. I set   `TEMP=/home/me/tmp` in there. Will see if this works or not. I had to restart the installation from start. It takes long time.  This might be something that TL installation should address. May be put a warning message before or something, that this can happen. In Manjaro package manager, there is an option there in the GUI to change TMP location so it is easy to see and change.

Comment: you can temporarily resize `/tmp`, e.g. `sudo mount -o remount,size=2G,noatime /tmp`. it will not be permanent and resets after reboot.

Comment: Assuming bash and that you are starting `install-tl` from a terminal, you could just do `export TMPDIR=/home/me/tmp` and then start `/install-tl` from the same terminal. No need to log out and in again in order for `/etc/environment` to work.

Comment: @daleif it does not work. I did as you suggested. Started new monitor and went through the whole thing again. It is still using `/tmp` here it is `./tlpkg/installer/xz/xz.x86_64-linux: (stdout): Write error: No space left on device
TLPDB::_install_package: Decompressing /tmp/KG0E6WST0K/iBJdrstsBN/pst-fractal.doc.tar.xz failed
Installation failed` and I check now
`>echo $TMPDIR
/home/me/tmp`
So TL did not use `TMPDIR`. I will try the answer below now and see if it works.  TL installation should not be this hard.

Comment: Please write to the texlive mailing list, they know the specifics of the installer, I don't. http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo, it is the list called `tex-live`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to temporarily resize `/tmp` by:

`sudo mount -o remount,size=<size>,noatime /tmp`

where `<size>` is the amount of disk space assigned, for example 2 Gigabytes. Change the size accordingly to your needs.

It will not be permanent and resets after reboot.

**Be careful though:**
as `/tmp` can be resized, it depends on how much RAM and storage in the `swap` partition is available. It should never be larger than the total amount of both, otherwise `Out of Memory` errors might occur.

E.g.:

A system with 2 GB RAM and a 6GB large `swap` partition could have assigned a total of 8GB for a `/tmp`. It is recommended, to be at least 1 GB below the total.

*Side note*: the size of a `/tmp` folder is usually half the size of available RAM.

Comment: I am trying `sudo mount -o remount,size=10G,noatime /tmp` now and will see if it works. Have to start TL installation again. Takes very long time